# Invertir Selección de una columna EXCEL

Tags: excel

Tengo un problema que parece ser bastante básico pero no logro encontrar la solución.
Necesito selecciónar todo lo que NO dice "FALSO" en la columna que seleccioné. O en su defecto, poder copiar solo las filas que no digan "FALSO" o algo por el estilo.
En síntesis, preciso COPIAR las filas que dicen "B60", "B30", etc.[image: Screenshot Excel]

Comment: Tal cual lo estás diciendo, no se puede hacer, salvo con VBA, pero si a lo mejor escribes qué es lo que quieres conseguir hacer al final, se pueda encontrar una solución.

Comment: Gracias por responder @ElierSánchezE-Infantes . La idea en sintesis es:
Cuando ingreso un valor en la columna E (que refiere a cantidad), necesito que se llene otra lista (que se encuentra en otra hoja del libro) donde en una columna me indique la cantidad (columna E) y su correspondiente a la columna D.
Ejemplo, pongo un 2 en E8 y un 3 en E13. En otra hoja, necesito que aparezca :
Fila 1 (2 | B30) y Fila 2 (3 | B60)
Espero haberme expresado bien. Muchas gracias

Comment: Pues efectivamente solo con fórmulas no veo ninguna manera de hacerlo. tendrás que programar algo en VBA para poder hacerlo. ¿Cuál es el objetivo de esa lista en la otra hoja? ¿Tener un subtotal de cada artículo o qué?

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes ok! particularmente casi nunca programé en VBA, pero veré cómo me las arreglo. La otra hoja es un Remito, es decir, en la hoja que muestro en la imagen, el usuario indica la cantidad de c/producto nombrado por su articulo (B30, B50, etc..) y en la sig. hoja se completa este remito, es decir una lista, indicando la cantidad y su respectivo artículo.

Comment: Es que creo que podrías hacer lo que quieres usando una tabla dinámica, pero posiblemente tendrías que modificar un poco el Excel actual que se ve en la pantalla, ese es el problema. Pero luego para sacar totales por piezas, a ti te sería más fácil. Es más, podrías sacar total por artículo, peros sabiendo a a qué pedido pertenece cada cuantía

Comment: Acabo de hacer eso, y CASI funciona a la perfección. Armé todo eso y lo puse en un macro, para que haga todo clickeando un botón. El único problema que surgió es que, el macro me pasa los valores de la Tabla Dinámica que había en el momento que la grabé. Hay una manera de que eso sea genérico?

Comment: Sí, las tablas dinámicas tienen una propiedad que se llama [Cambiar los datos de origen en una tabla dinámica](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/cambiar-los-datos-de-origen-en-una-tabla-din%C3%A1mica-afd93524-f7de-432c-84d0-3896fbbc2577)

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar, pero no me actualiza los datos

Comment: ¿Has probado a [Actualizar los datos de tabla dinámica](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/actualizar-los-datos-de-tabla-din%C3%A1mica-6d24cece-a038-468a-8176-8b6568ca9be2) después de actualizar el rango de datos de origen?

Comment: Ahí puede ser una solución! Te agradezco un montón